# iOS7 homescreen app reset does not delete offline database

Tags: html, safari, ios7, homescreen

We build a HTML5/Web based app using appcache manifest and websql offline database for use on mobile devices.

On iOS, until < 7, I would go to the settings app, look for Safari, and there delete cookies and data and this would clear data not only for the Safari Browser but also for all HTML Homescreen apps.

With iOS 7, this does not seem to clean everything. At least, the offline database seems to remain. I noticed this when we added another table to the code and in order to use it I wanted to start fresh on the device.

have not found anything about this, habe been reading http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

So, the big question: how to clear settings, storage, cache for homescreen apps in iOS 7?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this won't help much, but you can just 'DROP' the table(s) you are using, obviously this is done manually, and it's ugly, but since you can't delete the database, the best option is to delete the tables.